# Rails - Nearby cities in existing query which joins city table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, join

I have the following models:

```
class User
 has_one :player
 belongs_to :city
end

class Player
 belongs_to :user
end

class City
 has_many :users
end
```

Each City has a **latitude** and **longitude** attributes.

I have the following query (it's a little bit longer, but what matters is the city part) that I use to get players which associated users are from a particular city.  As this:

```
def self.search(city)
  self.includes(:user => :city).
  where(['cities.name = ?', city])
end
```

How would I change this query to get professors which users associated cities are near by (10 kilometers for example) the given city?

EDIT: I have this method in the City model which gives me the closest city given a particular radius (in km), latitude and longitude:

```
  def near_by(latitude,longitude,radius)
    City.select("cities.*,
                6371 *
                acos(cos(radians(#{latitude})) *
                cos(radians(cities.latitude)) *
                cos(radians(cities.longitude) - radians(#{longitude})) +
                sin(radians(#{latitude}))*sin(radians(cities.latitude)))
                AS km_away").group('km_away ASC').having('km_away <= ?', radius)
  end
```

**EDIT2**: Here is what I have so far in order to combine both queries:

```
# Pass a city object to the search instead of a city name, so we can use lat and long

def self.search(city)
  self.includes(:user => :city).
  where(['cities.id IN (?)', City.near_by(city.latitude,city.longitude)])
end
```

But is this a good approach? If so, how can I get the professors ordered by proximity to the passed city???

Answer (score 0):

For working with geographic data, I recommend you check out the [Geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) as described in this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder).

From the readme:
With geocoded objects you can do things like this:

```
obj.nearbys(30)                      # other objects within 30 miles
obj.distance_from([40.714,-100.234]) # distance from arbitrary point to object
obj.bearing_to("Paris, France")      # direction from object to arbitrary point
```

Comment: I think this is more like a comment than an answer...But thanks anyways.